# Using R and hidden Markov models to predict pseudorandom binary sequences better than P > .5?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model, binary-data

I would to predict a pseudo-random binary sequence of 0's and 1's.
I am thinking of using the HMM package in R.

I have a binary sequence like ... 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 x(n+1)? with thousands of values. What I would like is to get automatic estimation for x(n+1), computing their prob.matrix automatically every time.

The question is to know, if a HMM (or any other algorithm) can provide P > .5 for binary events that pass random tests, BUT are generated by deterministic algorithms, like LCG.

Something like that; http://www.stanford.edu/class/stats366/hmmR2.html BUT using a data file with the binary sequence, so prob.matrix can't be estimated before.
thank you

Comment: It depends on *which* "random tests" the PRG passes. Nowadays most batteries of tests include various runs tests and sequential correlation tests, sometimes extending for 8, 32, or even longer windows. In *principle,* then, an algorithm that uses larger neighborhoods to make predictions has a chance of improving over $0.5$, but--by the same lights--it would be hopeless to try an algorithm based on shorter windows. Now consider how many states a longer window would contain and how long the sequence would have to be to estimate transition probabilities... .

Comment: Well, but would be possible to algorithmically (auto)estimate how many states, windows for a given ie; sequence of length n=1000?.

Comment: I've upload a PRBSquence of n=1000 to estimate for a HMM: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7453430)

Comment: No way. Suppose you use a (tiny) window of four, for example: that comprises $2^4=16$ states, requiring estimation of $16\times 16=256$ transitions. A sequence of $1000$ gives an average of just four occurrences of each transition: the standard error of estimate of the probability would be an order of magnitude larger than the probability itself! You would need a sequence of *billions* (and likely many more) to have any hope of detecting fairly large deviations from perfect randomness and *quadrillions* to detect the tiny ones that might exist.